# `CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization` perform action after the user accepts

Tags: ios8, cllocationmanager

Ive update my app to include `[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`. Is it possible to start an update after the user gives permission? In iOS7 i would use the users location when the view loads, however now there is one extra step and as a result my method is not using a valid latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to perform the action in the `CLLocationManager` `Delegate` method ;

```
// Location Manager Delegate Methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

This method gets called after the user gives permission to use location services. Or if the user has already given access then it will automatically get called. If you only want to call a certain method once you can do:

```
// Location Manager Delegate Methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
   CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
   if(location !=nil){
   //we got a location
   //<YOUR METHOD GOES HERE>
   [manager stopUpdatingLocation];



   }
}
```